# In node_modules file i am getting Angular genric error while using fontawesome in angular12

Tags: angular, angular12

Generic type 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration' requires 7 type argument(s).

18     static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<FaStackComponent, "fa-stack", never, { "size": "size"; }, {}, never, ["*"], false>;

i want to access fa icons in angular.